# Selecting proper resistance based on tolerance

Tags: resistors, tolerance

I want to replicate a project.

The specification lists several resistances.
But they only specify the value of the resistance.

I went to buy resistances, but they first had me select a tolerance.

These were 0.1%, 1%, and 5%.

Which one should i pick?
Please keep in mind, these are going to be smd resistances (i don't know if that matters).

EDIT:
Here is the picture of the schematic:
[image]

Here is a list of the component's values:

[image]

There are two other resistors not listed here. They are the voltage divider that will drop 5V to 2.5V, for the Vbias.
Each of these tw oresistors is 1M Ohm.

Operating voltage of the OpAmps (Vbias) is 2.5V (produced by the voltage divider).

EDIT:
I actualy got these components.
They are all Though-Hole components.

In the first part i will name the component in the schematic, and then i will mention the component i bought for that specific component.

Do you think the components i picked will be good enough for this circuit?

```
R1 and R3: THT 10kΩ 0.4W ±1% Ø1.9x3.7mm 50ppm/° (M0.4W-10K)
R2: THT, 2kΩ, 0.6W, ±1%, Ø2.5x6.8mm, 50ppm/°C (M0.6W-2K)
R4: THT, 36kΩ, 0.6W, ±1%, Ø2.5x6.8mm, 50ppm/°C (M0.6W-36K)
Rbias: THT 100kΩ 0.4W ±1% Ø1.9x3.7mm 50ppm/&deg (M0.4W-100K)
Rdiv1,2: THT, 1MΩ, 0.6W, ±1%, Ø2.5x6.8mm, 50ppm/°C (M0.6W-1M)
---------------
C: Capacitor ceramic, 100pF, 100V, P350-N1000, ±5%, THT, 5mm, -55÷85°C (CCK-100P)
Decoupling capacitors for the 3 ICs: Ceramic Capacitor, 100nF, 100V, Y5V, -20÷+80%, THT, 5mm, -55÷85°C (CCK-100N)
```

Comment: You forgot to say what the resistance affects and how much of that affect you can tolerate: DC voltage, AC voltage, frequency of an oscillator?

Comment: Just curious, what's this circuit supposed to do?

Comment: @td127This corcuit is connected to a resistance, and produced a square pulse, that the width of the square pulse is proportionate to the resistance measured.

Comment: Thanks. You won’t be able to get a capacitor tighter than 1% and the final opamp output swing has very poor tolerance so there’s little point buying resistors better than 1%. The absolute values of the R1/R2 and the R3/R4 pair are not critical, only their ratio. R1=9.81 and R2=1.98 is a ratio of 4.95 so pick a standard 1% for R2, say 10.0K, then R1 should be the closest value to 49.5K, which would be 49.9K 1%. R3/R4 ratio is 34.9/9.88 = 3.53 so pick R3 = 10.0K and R4 = closest to 35.3K = 35.7K. (P.S. does this circuit really work? It didn't work in my simulation - output pegged.)

Comment: @td127 To make this work: Remove Rpath (optional - but its how i do it), and place the resistor to be "read", where the Rs is in the schematic.

Comment: @td127 Thank you very much for your effort. I actually got some components (bought before i asked this question - arrived now). I updated the question with the components i got and their correspondence with the components of the schematic. Could you please check it out and see if the parts i got will fit for this particular circuit? A million thanks....

Comment: Yes, those values are fine. I got the simulation to work. You know what – you don’t really need that lower left opamp at all. Assuming a single supply +5V rail-to-rail opamp, its output is a 3.5V square centered around 2.5V, in phase with the 5V square from the upper right opamp. You may as well just connect the upper right opamp’s output to Rbias directly, making Rbias a little larger to compensate for the larger input voltage swing.

Comment: @td127 Thank you for your reccomendations about the components! I find it surprising that the circuit can work without one oparmp, considering pages have been written about this circuit in an academic report. I would have no problem sending this to you, but its in greek. I have to note that the Vbias is not 5v, but 2.5V. Do you still have the simulation file?

Comment: Moderators get testy when comment conversations go on too long - moved to an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moved long comment discussion to Answer so I could add pretty pictures.

To answer the original question, you don’t need particularly precise resistors for this circuit. The capacitor is 1% at best, and the current that Vout feeds R1 depends on how close to the rails the Vout opamp can reach, which adds uncertainty to the overall tolerance (1% error if opamp only swings 0.05V to 4.95V). So 1% resistors are just fine.

Here is the original circuit with convenient values, assuming single supply +5V rail and rail-to-rail opamps.

The V0 opamp swings the full 0V to 5V.

The V1 opamp has a gain of 1/5 so swings 1V, centered around 2.5V, so from 2V to 3V, inverted.

The V2 opamp has a gain of 3 so swings 3V, centered around 2.5V, so from 1V to 4V, inverted again.

This V2 voltage feeds the integrator current through the 100K plus resistance under measurement, R.

For R=0, the current through the 100K is (4-2.5)/100K or (1-2.5)/100K, or +/-15uA.

For R=200K, current is (4-2.5)/300K or (1-2.5)/300K, or +/-5uA.

[image]

If we instead remove the V2 opamp and drive the integrator straight from V0 then the only change is the driving signal swings 5V instead of 4V.

By changing the fixed resistor to 166K we get the same +/-15uA we had before for R=0.

For R=334K, current is (5-2.5)/(166+334) = 5uA.

So the 4 opamp circuit yields a 5-15uA range for a 0-200K measurement.

The 3 opamp circuit yields the same 5-15uA range for a 0-334K measurement.

C sets the frequency range.

[image]

Here is a simulation of the 3 opamp version using rail-to-rail opamps:

[image]

EDIT #2:
If you want to achieve exact equivalency to the original 4 opamp circuit, that can be done with one more resistor. The R5/R6 network divides down the Vout signal to exactly what the original V2 output was, and their parallel impedance is chosen to duplicate the 100K Rbias.

[image]

OK, so that's how you do it with 3 opamps.

But now I have a question: This circuit is just an RC oscillator. Why on earth would you use 4 or even 3 opamps for such a thing? There is a very common 1 opamp circuit for an RC oscillator, why not use that?

I don't think adding more opamps makes the final measurement any more accurate: you're still limited by the tolerance of the R and C and the opamp's output swing consistency. If there's some reason for all the extra complexity I'd like to hear it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying to figure out how this works. I read the docs on the original circuit. T1 generates a square pulse; this sets the comparison threshold, in which T4 will generate an output. T2 modulates the width of the square, which will "hit" the resistance, T3 will produce a triangle pulse that is compared to the to the threshold voltage for the creation of the output voltage. I don't understand how removing one OpAmp will make the circuit complete its job... I have three other questions: 1. You said you didnt choose rail to rail OpAmps. But their voltage is 5V, what exactly

Comment: Do you mean? 2. The most important thing is this. You said the old circuit worked for "0-200K" and your iteration works for "0-334K". What are the units you are referring to? Ohms? Because i read the docs and for my circuit, it said 300KΩ < Rs < 1 ΜΩ. (Finally, what software are you using to make the simulation?). Really thank you very much! I really appreciate the effort you gave to this.

Comment: @user1584421 I re-did the LTspice simulation with a rail-to-rail opamp. You can select Rbias and C to adjust to the desired R range to be measured. The triangle will rise and fall according to i=C*(ΔV/ΔT), where ΔV is 1 (from 2 to 3V), and ΔT is pulse width you’re measuring (the time it takes C to ramp from 2 to 3V or from 3V to 2V). The current i, which flows through the resistor under test as well as through the capacitor, in the 4 opamp circuit is (V2-2.5)/(Rbias +R) = 1.5/(Rbias +R). The current in the 3 opamp version is (V0-2.5)/(Rbias + R) = 2.5/(Rbias +R).

Comment: Thank you, but, in other words, can the same functionality be achieved with three OpAmps, like the circuit you designed?

Comment: @user1584421 If you are asking “can the 3 opamp circuit exactly duplicate the original 4 opamp circuit?” the answer is yes. See edit #2 in Answer.

Answer (score 2):

This will be application specific. Component tolerances maybe crucial for circuit behavior, or they might not matter at all. One example of each is resistors in filters might need to be fairly tight values, if the tolerance is too much the filter may not realize the correct transfer function. For resistors where tolerance isn't as important, pullup resistors for low speed digital signals can be basically any tolerance you want, the actual value isn't as important as the fact that the resistor is there in the first place (and is the correct order of magnitude).

Another thing to consider is that not all resistances values are made in a given tolerance range. There are more 1% tolerance resistor values than there are 10%. So if you need a 13.7kΩ resistor for example you may not be able to find a 5% or 10% value (or it will be more expensive to get).

[Here are some different resistor values for each tolerance](http://www.rfcafe.com/references/electrical/resistor-values.htm)

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question. Please take a look at it, if you have the time,

Answer (score 1):

Smaller numbers are better, but also more expensive.

So 0.1% will work but will cost more than the others,

The others may work, it depends on the task each resistor is doing.

In small quantities 1% and 5% cost about the same

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb nowadays is "1% unless specified otherwise". 5% might be ok but for the negligible cost different it's not worth the risk. 0.1% are still specialized/expensive enough that I would expect a designer to specify them if they needed that kind of precision.

---

> Thank you! I updated the question with the components i got. Could you please take a quick look just to make sure that my components would work fine?

Given that I have no idea what the circuit is supposed to do (no I can't read the foreign language text on it), I can't say for sure how important the values are.

What I will say is that the list of values you have given is very strange, some of them are not standard values at all and others are standard, but only in [E192](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_series_of_preferred_numbers#Lists) (0.5%) which is a pretty rare series.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the question with the components i got. Could you please take a quick look just to make sure that my components would work fine?